# Combine Date + Time Zone and Look Back 10 minutes

Tags: postgresql

I am fairly new to Postgresql, but still have some questions. I have a table with two columns I need to filter by:

mlx_date is date (data_type)
mlx_time is time (time without time zone)

My query is

```
SELECT
     
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_firstname, 
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_lastname, 
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_num, 
    ns_medication.mlx_date, 
    ns_medication.mlx_time, 
    ns_medication.mlx_item
FROM
    ns_medication
    INNER JOIN
    ip_visit_1
    ON 
        ns_medication.mlx_acctnum = ip_visit_1.ipv1_num
    WHERE
TO_CHAR(ns_medication.mlx_date+ns_medication.mlx_time, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') >= CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
```

The error message is operator does not exist: text >= time with time zone
LINE 16: ...lx_date+ns_medication.mlx_time, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') >= CURRENT...
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I cannot find anything that will allow me to combine these two columns and find anything within the past ten minutes. Does anyone have a suggestion of a function I might try using?

Comment: Get rid of the `to_char()` is useless to begin with and the cause of your error. `ns_medication.mlx_date+ns_medication.mlx_time`  will already return a `timestamp` which you can compare directly to `current_date`

Comment: If I do ns_medication.mlx_date+ns_medication.mlx_time > = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE it returns everything from today's date, not within the last ten minutes.

Comment: You need to use `current_timestamp` not `current_date` if you want the last 10 minutes

Comment: This begs the question why not a `timestamp with time zone` column that combines the two? Then you would only have to look at one column. You can decompose that column to get  `date` and `time` if needed. It saves you one column of storage and the overhead of ending up creating a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_firstname, 
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_lastname, 
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_num, 
    ns_medication.mlx_date, 
    ns_medication.mlx_time, 
    ns_medication.mlx_item
FROM
    ns_medication
    INNER JOIN
    ip_visit_1
    ON 
        ns_medication.mlx_acctnum = ip_visit_1.ipv1_num
    WHERE
 WHERE
ns_medication.mlx_time >= CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
AND ns_medication.mlx_date = CURRENT_DATE
```